# Why am I not getting two positive pivots for this symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination, positive-definite

I'm watching Gilbert Strang's linear algebra [lecture on positive definite matrices](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/symmetric-matrices-and-positive-definiteness/) and I have a question about the example he uses in the last 10-15 minutes of the video.

Strang is demonstrating the claim that all pivots of a positive definite matrix are positive using the example of
$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}5&2\\2&3\end{bmatrix}$$
He finds that the pivots are $5$ and $\frac{11}{5}$, but I'm not sure how he gets the second one. Elimination $(2\text{row}_1-5\text{row}_2\to\text{row}_2)$ yields for me
$$\begin{bmatrix}5&2\\0&-11\end{bmatrix}$$
which suggests to me that the pivots are $5$ and $\color{red}{-11}$. But that can't be right, as Strang goes on to say that the product of the pivots is equal to the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$, and indeed: if one of the pivots is $5$ (no argument there), this means $5x=11\implies x=\frac{11}{5}$. Furthermore, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are both positive $(4\pm\sqrt5)$ which means both pivots must be positive.

How do I get $\frac{11}{5}$? Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about what a pivot is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strang doesn't multiply rows until the end. His row operation is subtracting $2/5$ of row $1$ from row $2$ to get
$$
\pmatrix{5&2\\ 0&11/5}
$$
Note that such row operations do not affect the determinant. Note also that the other row operations, i.e. row-switching and multiplying rows by scalars **do** affect the determinant.

Your row operation is tantamount to doing this and then multiplying the second row by $-5$.

It seems that for GS, pivots in this context refer to the entries on the diagonal after row reducing *using only the operation of* adding one multiple of a row to another.

Comment: Point of order: my phone autocorrected "multiply by scalars" to "multiply by salads".

Comment: Salad is good for you

Comment: Salads are made from vegetables that are grown in *fields*, so perhaps we should be using them for vector spaces after all

Comment: The best example I know, of autocorrect, was an attempt, in an answer by Igor Rivin, to use the French phrase equivalent to "cutting edge" http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85610/klein-bottle-exception-to-the-heawood-conjecture

Comment: That's hard to beat

Comment: Now that you mention it, I must have overlooked a comment GS might have made in his "basics of matrix multiplication" lecture about only altering one row and combining it with another. I figured my operations accomplish the same thing, but I stand corrected. I should have noticed something was off when the determinants didn't work out to the same value. Thanks!